# Execute and update value from converter when validation fails

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having a problem with **p:inputText** when using it with converter and validator.

Here is my code [.xhtml]:

```
<p:inputText
        id = "iban"
        value = "#{testBean.iban}"
        converter = "ibanConverter"
        required = "true"
        validator = "#{testBean.validateIban}" >
    <p:ajax event = "change"
            proces = "@this"
            update = "iban"
            global = "false"
            listener = #{testBean.getDataFromIban()} />
</p:inputText>
```

The problem occurs when the wrong value is entered, which means that validator fails and therefore converted iban (input is converted to uppercase and so on) is not shown.

I know that conversion happens before validation, but is there a way that converted value is shown (updated field value from converter) if validator fails?

At the moment, only the validator message is displayed when entering the wrong value.

Comment: Hi i'm also facing same issue, you found any solution.

Comment: Validation is failed but on input tag I need to show converted value that has been converted using converter but as validation is failed, converted value is not reflected on input field.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm still looking for alternative ways to fix the problem.